Print only some bits from a logic vector into terminal
So I have a 16 bit logic vector. However, when I print this onto the screen I want to decide how many bits (starting from bit 0) are printed on the screen. The remaining space could be either filled with space characters for padding or just be left empty.
I could write a function that assembles such a string one character at a time. However, is there a direct method to achieve this using the built in features of SystemVerilog?
EDIT:
I have tried to write code where the logic vector itself or its string representation is sliced like this:
module tb_6;

    logic [15:0] bits;
    int          size;
    string       bits_str;
        string       str;

    task do_st;
        bits = 16'b1011101100010111;
        size = 5;
        bits_str = $sformatf("%b",bits);
                str = bits_str[size-1:0];
        $display("%b", bits);
        $display(str);
    endtask

    initial begin

        do_st;

    end

endmodule

The last version of my experiment uses a separate task called do_st and try to slices the string format of the logic vector. However, regardless of whether I do bits[size-1:0] or I do bits_str[size-1:0], I get the same error message:
 Range must be bounded by constant expressions.

Is it really impossible to slice a signal using a variable for the slice size?

SystemVerilog does not allow part selects having a variable widths. But for string types, there is a substr() method.
task do_st;
        bits = 16'b1011101100010111;
        size = 5;
        bits_str = $sformatf("%b",bits);
        str = bits_str.substr(bits_str.len()-size,bits_str.len()-1)l
        $display("%b", bits);
        $display(str);
endtask


It's because SystemVerilog is a statically-typed language, and the width of a array is part of its type.

VHDL treats vectors like strings, which is why it's slower than other languages.

This is what I wrote and it does what I need:
function string logic_slice_str (input logic [15:0] bits, input shortint size, input byte padding = " ", input byte justify = 0);

    string bit_str;
    string pad_str;
    string str;
    byte   ch;
    int    i;

    assert (size > 0) else $fatal("Invalid value for size");

    bit_str = "";
    pad_str = {(16-size){padding}};

    for (int i=size-1; i>=0; i--) begin
        case (bits[i])
                1'b0: ch = "0";
                1'b1: ch = "1";
                1'bZ: ch = "Z";
                default: ch = "X";
        endcase     
        bit_str = {bit_str, ch};
    end

    if (justify==0)
        str = {pad_str, bit_str};
    else
        str = {bit_str, pad_str};

    return str;

endfunction

I still do not understand why I can't take a slice using a variable e.g str = bits_str[size-1:0]. I am very surprised to see that. Also, there should be built in fuction to do something like this which possibly does not exist. Very strange.
